Activate virtual environment automatically when running container interactively
I'm creating a virtual environment during the building process of my Docker image:
FROM ubuntu

[...]

RUN virtualenv --python=python3.10 /home/obj_det \
    && source /home/obj_det/bin/activate \
    && pip install -r /home/requirements.txt

So, I can run the container interactively:
docker run -it --rm --name some_name image_name

and activate the environment by:
/home/obj_det/bin/activate

I would like to do it automatically, so that when I run the container interactively a shell opens up with the container active already.
I tried using an entrypoint script:
#!/bin/bash
source /home/obj_det/bin/activate
exec "$@"

and copying it during the image build process, by adding this to the Dockerfile:
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

but it doesn't work, when I run the container the environment is not active, I just have a basic terminal:
root@193f0746fa3b:~# 

I tried executing the entrypoint from within the container:
/entrypoint.sh

and still nothing. But, if I explicitly execute the command:
source /home/obj_det/bin/activate

the environment is activated:
(obj_det) root@193f0746fa3b:~#

How can I fix this?
I would generally avoid using a virtual environment in the container, but I need to do it because I have to install some Python packages, and for some reason they conflict with system packages, so having a separate environment is (should be!) the easiest solution.

It seems like Activate python virtualenv in Dockerfile covers this space pretty well already; consider its suggestions to not use a virtual environment at all, and to use ENV PATH=... in place of trying to run the activate script fragment.  I'd expect the entrypoint script you show should work (consider changing the last line to exec "$@" to run the CMD, maybe as overridden, instead of fixing the container to only run a shell; consider using standard . instead of non-standard source).  How do you start the container and what result do you see?
